# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertAdjacentHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, html

I'm so motivated guy who wants to be Javascript Developer. Debugs are killing me. I think this part is the hardest part ever of our begining. Anyway;
I'm in one project. Kinda last part of it.
I have this error, which I could not find solution.

My Javascript codes are here:

```js
var arayuz = (function(){
    
    var Domstrings = {
        InputType:'.add__type',
        InputDescription:'.add__description',
        InputValue:'.add__value',
        InputBtn:'.add__btn',
        IncomeList:'income__list',
        ExpenseList:'expenses__list'
            
    };

    return {
        getInput: function() {
            return {
                type: document.querySelector(Domstrings.InputType).value, // Will be either inc or exp
                description: document.querySelector(Domstrings.InputDescription).value,
                value: document.querySelector(Domstrings.InputValue).value
            };
        },

        // and the part where I got stuck...

        addListItem: function(obj,type){
            //Default HTML
            var html, newHtml, element;
            if(type == 'inc'){
                element = Domstrings.IncomeList;
                html='<div class="item clearfix" id="income-%id%"><div class="item__description">%description%</div><div class="right clearfix"><div class="item__value">+%value%</div><div class="item__delete"><button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button></div></div></div>'
            } else if(type == 'exp'){
                element = Domstrings.ExpenseList;
                html='<div class="item clearfix" id="expense-%id%"><div class="item__description">%description%</div><div class="right clearfix"><div class="item__value">- %value%</div><div class="item__percentage">21%</div><div class="item__delete"><button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button></div></div></div>';
            }
            // Change HTML
            newHtml = html.replace('%id%', obj.id);
            newHtml = newHtml.replace('%description%', obj.description);
            newHtml = newHtml.replace('%value%', obj.value);
        
            // YAZILARIN ÖNCESİNE EKLENMESİNİ EKLEYEN HTMLADJACENT METODU KULLANIMI
        
            document.querySelector(element).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newHtml);        
        
        },

        getDomstrings:function(){
            return Domstrings;
        }
       
    } ;       
        
})();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your error literally means that you've tried to access a property named `insertAdjacentHTML` on something that was `null` (as `null` and `undefined` can't have properties).

There's only a single line where this can occur:

```
document.querySelector(element).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newHtml);
```

The problem is, that you've forgotten to write a dot (or a # if they're IDs) before your `IncomeList` and `ExpenseList` selectors.

Without it, the code will try to look up an element with *tag name* of `income__list` and `expenses__list`.

This will result in returning `null` from `.querySelector` (as there's no such element), and you get an error, when you try to call `insertAdjacentHTML` on it.

Answer (score 0):

**Your Code**

```
IncomeList: 'income__list',

ExpenseList: 'expenses__list'
```

**solution**

```
IncomeList: '.income__list', 

ExpenseList: '.expenses__list'

// add dot you've selected class name but missing dot
```